# On the inputs and outputs of auto-encoder neural network

Tags: python, deep-learning, autoencoder

I am reading about autoencoder these days. Autoencoders actually reconstruct the original input and also  help in dimensionality reduction as below :

At encoder:

X : the input data

c:  the resulted code after encoder.

At decoder:

c: The input data

X' : is the output where (X - X') should be almost equals to 0.

My question is about the input X and c.  What should it be ? can X be binary data or decimal ? .. the same of C, can it be binary? or it must be decimal.

The other thing, encoder and decoder must be together or we can use them separately? I mean we use the encoder to get the output of encoder c, and then we can modify or change c then we use the decoder, Is that possible? What's the percentage of c compared with X, .. I mean the size of c should be half, quarter the size of X ? or it can be whatever ...

Thank you.

Comment: You should try to use some autoencoder and see what it expects, what it gives back and how big it is. [Building Autoencoders in Keras](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html)